# my view hides some of my labels

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, subviews

I have a textfield in my view. Below that I have created a view and I placed tableview in that view. The table view height is not constant it is coming from service but while entering data in  text field  there is no problem bcoz table view is visible. I have selected one row but if I want to change the textfield again, I am deleting data in textfield when there is no data in my text field still tableview is visible.

```
       - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {



          }
```

Are there any modifications still I'm missing in textfield should change character method?  what shall i write in this  method .Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should also wirte this in your text field delegate method.

```
if ( [textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
   yourTableView.hidden=YES;
    return;
}
else
{
  yourTableView.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: if i click the textfield then only my tableview hides otherwise it is still visible

Comment: i do not getting what you really required. can you elaborate a little more

Comment: while deleting the data in textfield my textfield becomes empty.and nou table view is not visible ok. but if i want to enter again the data it is not taking the data

Comment: or you can use this delegate method to hide and show table view :- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  . It is called when you resign first responder

Comment: yes . i use this delegate method. my problem solved. but   new problem came into picture. if i am entering the data into textfield after deletion totally my tableview is not visible and textfield is not taking data means the data is invisible

Comment: then you should check the current value in textfield while entering data and if the data in textfield is not nil then enter tableview.hidden=NO;   and please vote my last answer if it was working. you can atleast do this